# Windows ContextMenuHandler names - Document conflict?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell

Microsoft page on [Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers) has a section on **Handler Names**

It gives an example of the **Handler Subkey Name** type for an `IContextMenu` interface:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   MyProgram.1
      ShellEx
         ContextMenuHandlers
```

Then it says:

> create a subkey underneath the "Handler Subkey name" key whose name
> is the string version of the CLSID of the Shell extension.

But then down below in the section **Example of an Extension Handler Registration** it says:

> To enable a particular handler, create a subkey under the extension
> handler type key with the name of the handler. ... Set the default
> value of the name subkey to the string form of the handler's GUID.

And gives an example of:

```
Shellex
   ContextMenuHandler
      MyCommand
         (Default) = {00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444}
```

So in the first section it says to use the CLSID string under `ContextMenuHandler` and doesn't mention a Default Value.   The second it says to use a (friendly) name of the handler and set the Default Value to the CLSID/GUID.

Next step, looked in the Registry and I see it done both ways, sometimes using GUID, sometimes using a friendly name with GUI in default value.

Which is correct?  Or does it not really matter (which appears to be the case)?

Comment: Yes, both works not sure it's documented (shhhh don't tell any one but look at DCA_AddItemsFromKey function from http://218.94.103.156:8090/download/developer/xpsource/Win2K3/NT/shell/lib/dka.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way:

This is the most efficient way:

```
Shellex
   ContextMenuHandler
      {00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444}
         (Default) = UniqueFriendlyName
```

This also works but takes an extra attempt to look up the {GUID}

```
Shellex
   ContextMenuHandler
      UniqueFriendlyName
         (Default) = {00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444}
```